# How to count the X and Y coordinates of a point from the object's rotation (angle) and leg's length?

Tags: actionscript, rotation, coordinates, angle

Can anybody tell me how I can count the B point's coordinates (see attached image... or not as I am a new user...pf!). I know the arrow's rotation - so the angle (let's say it is -120), A's coordinates (0, 0) - A is the middle point of the arrow, and that the distance between A and B is 50 px.
Thanks a lot!

```
.B
 \
  \ 50 px
   \
    \
     .A
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some ordinary trigonometry to me.  Remember that in mathematics you calculate in radians counter-clockwise from the right.  Setting the rotation property of DisplayObjects in Flash, on the other hand, is measured in degrees clockwise from the top.  So there's always some fun conversion to do if you're doing this math in order to rotate a DisplayObject.  In the example though I'm assuming you just care about finding B's coordinates relative to A, given a known rotation and absolute distance between them.

```
import flash.geom.Point;

var angle:Number = -120;
var radian:Number = angle * Math.PI / 180;
var length:Number = 50;
var aCoords:Point = new Point(100, 20); //example values for known coords of point A
var bCoords:Point = new Point(Math.cos(radian) * length + aCoords.x, Math.sin(radian) * length + aCoords.y);

trace(bCoords);
```